XCode add ContentView/View to UIView
I'm new to Xcode and I don't fully understand how to navigate and add to views.
I have a controller and I want to add the navigationlist within in the ContentView View to the UIView page, but I don't know how this works. I've added a loading label which shows fine, but no matter what I try, I cannot seem to add the contentview to the UIView/page.
//
//  HomeController.swift
//
//  Created by Me on 2024-10-26.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class LeaguesController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var theContainer: UIView!
    
    
    // MARK: - UI Components
    private let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .label
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .semibold)
        label.text = "Loading..."
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        return label
    }()
    
    
    // MARK: - LifeCycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupUI()
        
        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView:ContentView())
    addChild(childView)
    childView.view.frame = theContainer.bounds
    theContainer.addSubview(childView.view)
    childView.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - UI Setup
    private func setupUI() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapLogout))
        
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        self.view.addSubview(ContentView) //error
                
        
        
    }
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        let countries = countryList
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(countries, id: \.self) { country in
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text(country)) {
                            Image(systemName: "airplane")
                            Text(country)
                        }.padding()
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Destinations")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
        
    // MARK: - Selectors
    @objc private func didTapLogout() {
        
    }
}


Thanks for closing my question............. tried the linked quewtion already the answers do not work. I get an error stating that nil was found while implicitly unwrapping

That line doesn’t do anything that hasn’t been done already just delete it. But you likely need some basic tutorials.

You are trying to combine UIKit and SwiftUI - This is reasonably complicated. If you are just starting, stick with either SwiftUI or UIKit rather than trying to combine the two
